# Telethon userbot "You can't write in this chat (caused by SendMessageRequest)"

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, chatbot, telethon

I tried to write a user bot to join the chat and enter text, but it gives an error:

Unable to join the chat https://t.me/: You can't write in this chat (caused by SendMessageRequest)

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

import time

api_id = ''  #  api_id

api_hash = ''  #  api_hash

phone_number = ''  #  номер телефона



client = TelegramClient('userbot', api_id, api_hash)




client.connect()


if not client.is_user_authorized():

    client.send_code_request(phone_number)

    client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Введите код из СМС: '))




with open('linkss.txt', 'r') as f:

    links = f.readlines()



for link in links:

    try:`your text`

        time.sleep(3)

        chat = client.get_entity(link.strip())

        client.send_message(chat, 'Привет!')

    except Exception as e:

        print(f'Не удалось зайти в чат {link.strip()}: {e}')




client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some chats are restricted, or the account you're using is restricted one way or another, and you can't send messages (or perform other "write" actions) in the chat.

The only thing you can do to avoid the error is to not attempt to send messages to those chats in the first place.